# Nginx within docker start

Tags: docker, nginx, server, dockerfile

I can't start nginx in docker. 
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get install -y nginx  
RUN useradd nginx
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY vladislav.crt /etc/nginx/vladislav.crt
COPY vladislav.csr /etc/nginx/vladislav.csr
COPY vladislav.key /etc/nginx/vladislav.key
COPY dhparam.pem /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I just build my image using next command 
`docker build -t custom_nginx .`
`docker run --name nginx_test custom_nginx`
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Please add what error you got while trying to build the image?

Comment: @vijay my image just doesn't build without any error

Comment: @vijay is it docerfile correct?

Comment: Yes. I don't see any issue in your Dockerfile apart from missing tag (like `From image:tag` Example: `FROM ubuntu:16.04`) in the base image. You can also do a `--no-install-recommends` when apt-get installing packages. This will result in a smaller image size. Not necessary though. Can you post the screenshot of docker build command?

Comment: @vijay yes, it in next answer

Comment: @vijay must it work on localhost?

Comment: `docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name nginx_test custom_nginx` and check your localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

@vijay

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  73.22kB
Step 1/12 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 77be327e4b63
Step 2/12 : RUN apt update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4fb44426c756
Step 3/12 : RUN apt-get install -y nginx
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 005b9faefee0
Step 4/12 : RUN useradd nginx
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b60713d5cce3
Step 5/12 : ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a18a25afa878
Step 6/12 : COPY conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b1245c3f352d
Step 7/12 : COPY vladislav.crt /etc/nginx/vladislav.crt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5cc3e278e8fc
Step 8/12 : COPY vladislav.csr /etc/nginx/vladislav.csr
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e2d6824575a5
Step 9/12 : COPY vladislav.key /etc/nginx/vladislav.key
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ba28e5f7434b
Step 10/12 : COPY dhparam.pem /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f6e3e5c5f3d1
Step 11/12 : EXPOSE 80 443
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bd10f8b63f23
Step 12/12 : CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0ac3851b312d
Successfully built 0ac3851b312d
Successfully tagged custom_nginx:latest
```

after that when I run it by that
`root@maksym-X302UA:/etc/nginx# docker run --name nginx_test custom_nginx`
I get only empty string

Comment: Please remove this from the answer and add this as an edit to your question.